# NOT NULL constraint failed when linking a model with User

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='anon')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='anon')
    interest = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='nothing')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Username:%s' % self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(default='No title')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=220)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    user_post = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post')

class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='Anon', null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'comment:%s' % self.comment
```

In the post you can see I'm linking a post with the User. I read that you can access a users comments this way by using user.post_set.all(), so I gave it a try. When I attempt to migrate the change(adding the foriegn key in Post), I get an error.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:  
boardapp_post__new.user_post_id
```

I notice the post__new, so here is my view named new, which creates a post.

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post =     Post.objects.create(title=request.POST.get('post_title', ''),
        text=request.POST.get('post_text',''),vote=0

    )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_post', args=(post.id,)))
    return render(request, 'new.html')
```

I'm new to creating users in django and am confused as to where not null consraint is failing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate to your new database format, there should be a default `User` for the `user_post`s that already exist.
Django will try to fill this value for you in existing `user_post`s, but it doesn't know which value to chose, since `null` is not allowed in your current model.
Thus: you need to tell Django either 1) not to worry about Posts without a user (`null = True`) or 2) supply a default `User`, which is a bit harder (probably would require a function call that creates some dummy `User` on the fly).

So the easiest solution is to alter your `Post` model and change `user_post`:

```
user_post = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post', null=True)
```

Comment: I added null=true and migrated, get the same error when migrating

Comment: @BrandonParker Did you just `./manage.py migrate`, or `./manage makemigrations` before that (and after you changed the model)?

Comment: I did makemigrations then migrate

Comment: I messed up and didn't add the rest of models.py, which could be a factor. If you look at my post, I added my full models.py code

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because your model field is

`user_post = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post')`

it means every post will be assigned to a user(not null field).
From your view, you are not assigning any user to the post, so change your code to

```
post = Post.objects.create(title=request.POST.get('post_title', ''),
    text=request.POST.get('post_text',''), vote=0, user_post=request.user

)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem (see also my answer): the OP states they *migrated* their current model by adding the ForeignKey field, and that's causing the IntegrityError.

Comment: @Evert :  I don't think migration will give any error due to adding NOT NULL field, instead of it will prompt to add a default value to that field.

Comment: Yeah changing that view won't work because that column doesn't exist, since I can't get through the migration

Comment: You're right, Django normally asks for a (one-off) default. Since that didn't happen, it's something else, but apparently this doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes, currently it wont work, but once it resolve the current issue he may pass through this situation.